# Does python's glob function support wildcards with variable depth?

Tags: python, wildcard, glob

I'm writing a python script that uses this awkward glob syntax.

```
import glob    
F = glob.glob('./www.dmoz.org/Science/Environment/index.html')
F += glob.glob('./www.dmoz.org/Science/Environment/*/index.html')
F += glob.glob('./www.dmoz.org/Science/Environment/*/*/index.html')
F += glob.glob('./www.dmoz.org/Science/Environment/*/*/*/index.html')
F += glob.glob('./www.dmoz.org/Science/Environment/*/*/*/*/index.html')
```

Seems like there ought to be a way to wrap this is one line:

```
F = glob.glob('./www.dmoz.org/Science/Environment/[super_wildcard]/index.html')
```

But I don't know what the appropriate super wildcard would be.  Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry - it does not. You will have to probably write few lines of code using [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/starting/path/'):
    for myFile in files:
        if myFile == "index.html":
            print os.path.join(root, myFile)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is new, but glob CAN do this now.

For example,

```
F = glob.glob('./www.dmoz.org/Science/Environment/**/index.html', recursive=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have just released [Formic](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/formic) which implements exactly the wildcard you need - '**' - in an implementation of Apache Ant's [FileSet and Globs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns).

The search can be implemented:

```
import formic
fileset = formic.FileSet(include="/www.dmoz.org/Science/Environment/**/index.html")
for file_name in fileset.qualified_files():
    # Do something with file_name
```

This will search from the current directory. I hope this helps.

Comment: I actually find the ant wildcard process to be flawed when it comes to mixing includes and excludes. For example, you cannot express this filter using ant wildcards: "I want to include all files in dir a/b/c, but exclude all *.txt files except for readme.txt". The perforce implementation is much better, because it uses the ordering of your patterns to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfect, but works for me:

```
for i in range(max_depth):  
    components= ['./www.dmoz.org/Science/Environment',]+(['*']*i)+['index.html']
    fsearch=os.path.join(*components)
    fs_res=glob.glob(fsearch)
    if len(fs_res)==1:
        return fs_res[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

10 years later ... pathlib solution

```py
from pathlib import Path
F = Path("./www.dmoz.org/Science/Environment/").glob('**/*index.html')
```

Where `[super_wildcard]` = `**`.